# How to restart serproxy (osx)

Tags: flash, arduino

Like topic leads, i started it yesterday and all worked well, and i closed the terminal window. But now it seems like serproxy somehow has been "frozen" since when i launch it again, it replies failed to open comm port:

> Serproxy 0.2.0 - Tinker.it  Based on code by (C)1999 Stefano Busti,
>   (C)2005 David A. Mellis
>
> Waiting for clients
>
> Failed to open comm port - connection refused

Any idea what to do ? Been searching for solution for hours but can not find anything useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i solved the problem by only using **serial_device1=/dev/cu.usbmodem$$$** tty.usbmodem doesnt seem to work for serproxy, only for arduino IDE